# Submitting form with getJSON not succeeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, getjson

I'm working on Ruby-on-Rails. I'm trying to submit a form with JSON request.

HTML

```
<%= form_tag widgets_user_path(:format => "json"), :id => "testjsonform" do %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="math" id="sub1" class="left">
        <label for="sub1" class="laa">Math</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="history" id="sub2" class="left">
        <label for="sub2" class="laa">History</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="science" id="sub3" class="left">
        <label for="sub3" class="laa">Science</label>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'callback', "?" %>
        <div><%= submit_tag 'JSON', :id => "testjson" %></div>
<% end %>
```

application.js

```
$("#testjsonform").live("submit", function() {
    $.getJSON($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .success(function() {
        alert("success");
    })
    .error(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
    return false;
});
```

On console it shows the request is completed (200)

```
Started GET "/widgets/user.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=N8WsL3BATQiv9OWX4d29o62GOQgX9mXdt%2BBiVe%2FtzU%3D&cat%5B%5D=history&callback=%3F" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 12:52:35 +0530
Processing by WidgetsController#user as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"N8WsL3BATQiv9OWX4d29o62GOQgX9mXdt+BiVe/tzU=", "cat"=>["history"], "callback"=>"?"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
===================================== Categories
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

And in Google Chrome is shows the correct JSONP response

```
?({"user":{"fname":"Test","lname":"User","email":"testuser@testsite.com"}})
```

Everything seems correct; but still it gives me alert in error block. Why don't I get the success alert? What could possibly be wrong?
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Try to alert the error, which is given as a parameter to the error handler.

Comment: Does jQuery do an ajax or a jsonp call? For the first one, the callback parameter is neither needed nor allowed.

Comment: It is making JSON call and the callback parameter '?' is needed to correctly format the JSON response in controller. Can you help to how can I print/check the error type?

Comment: Valid JSON neither contains the question mark nor the braces. For getting the error object, see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: It is JSONP response actually. Will make the correction... (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2887214/707636)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I found where the problem is and came up with **(not so pretty)** solution...

The problem seems to be with URL encoding. (The way it is sending the "callback" parameter)

`$.getJSON(_form.attr("action"), _form.serialize(), function(data) { /* some code */ }` sends the request as follows

```
Started GET "/widgets/user.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&cat%5B%5D=4&callback=%3F&user=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 16:59:40 +0530
Processing by WidgetsController#user as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "cat"=>["4"], "callback"=>"?", "user"=>"3"}
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
===================================== Categories
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

I made some changes in `application.js` to decode the parameters.

```
var _url = _form.attr("action") + "?" + decodeURIComponent(_form.serialize());

$.getJSON(_url, function(data) {
    alert("success");
});
```

This sends the request as follows and also gave me success alert :) (see the parameters; extra "_" parameter also got added to it.)

```
Started GET "/widgets/user.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&cat[]=4&callback=jQuery17203027302643749863_1335526106006&user=3&_=1335526108045" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 16:58:28 +0530
Processing by WidgetsController#user as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "cat"=>["4"], "callback"=>"jQuery17203027302643749863_1335526106006", "user"=>"3", "_"=>"1335526108045"}
User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
===================================== Categories
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

Also I added `:method => "get"` to the `form`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set your form as `remote`? You can respond with javascript instead of JSON which can show on your page some rendered content:

```
# in your view
<%= form_tag widgets_user_path, :id => "testjsonform", remote: true do %>

# in *.js.erb
alert("<%= j params.to_yaml %>")
$('body').append("<%= j render something %>") # or other stuff for filling your "parent" page
```

Comment: The purpose is I'm writing this code to build widget (which can be placed on some user's site/blog). The script will hit a URL and it will return JSON data to populate data in the widget. This will help for my web application but not for others.