# Error parsing JSON string

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am having difficulty parsing a json string that appears to be valid json.

My code is the following.  I'm trying to grab some simple json from a URL.

```
import urllib2    
import simplejson
req = urllib2.Request("http://www.rentrent.org/RENT/Ads.aspx?xmin=-118.01925659179687&ymin=33.71948521132481&xmax=-117.68142700195314&ymax=33.85644642218431&bd=&ba=&pets=-1&type=2&throwErrorIfOverLimit=false&callback=xxx")  

opener = urllib2.build_opener()    
f = opener.open(req)    
content = f.read();    
print "content = " + content   # Appears to print valid json string
json = simplejson.loads(content)
```

I get an error on `simplejson.loads(content)`:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx) 
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

This is confusing because `content` appears to be a perfectly good json string.

I need to get to this data as individual elements.  Any ideas how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you post the JSON response?

Comment: You can get rid of the error by giving it valid json, or ignoring the failure. Need to see json.

Comment: I wanted to correct my last comment by saying we don't need to see the json at this point. I looked at the url and saw the data, though its convenient for everyone if a snippet is posted here.

Answer (score 3):

This is a jsonp api url. Its expecting to return to you a response wrapped in a function call xxx(). Look into how to handle jsonp. What you are currently getting is not actually valid jsonp. Its valid javascript.

Here is another question about the difference:
[What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

You can remove the callback param from your url and get back pure json:
http://www.rentrent.org/RENT/Ads.aspx?xmin=-118.01925659179687&ymin=33.71948521132481&xmax=-117.68142700195314&ymax=33.85644642218431&bd=&ba=&pets=-1&type=2&throwErrorIfOverLimit=false

**Update**

I overlooked that removing the callback param from the url doesn't actually tell this api to return JSON. It only prevents it from being wrapped into a function. The return value is still not json. It is javascript. To be specific, here is an example:

*Javascript From the return value*

```
{Status:'Success',
```

*JSON*

```
{'Status':'Success',
```

All of the keys need to be quoted. Your options are either:

1. See if the api supports a json return value instead of jsonp
2. Do a regex fix on the output to quote all of the keys before decoding

Comment: Thanks!    I see how it is no longer wrapped in a function call.   However it still won't parse.  I get a  `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting property name", s, end)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)`  Does that url return a valid json or am I parsing it incorrectly?

Comment: Some APIs (like Stripe's for example) will return JSONP if callback argument is provided, JSON otherwise.