# Ajax Requests to Facebook graph not working on IE

Tags: ajax, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, jsonp

I am developing a facebook app. I am trying to get the likes for urls as I am iterating through an array of urls and adding it to the div that should contain the likes. This is my ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  cache: false,
                  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?id='+videoUrl,
                  dataType : "json",
                  async: false,
                  header: "application/json",
                  success: function(data) {
                      if(data.shares == null) {
                          likeCount = 0;
                      } else {
                          likeCount = data.shares;
                      }
                  }
          });
```

This works perfectly fine on Chrome, Firefox, Safari. It doesn't work on any IE. I thought it was a caching issue. Notice that I added cache: false to the request. I tried JSONP and I get the likes but I am unable to access it outside of the request. I also tried adding this to my php:

```
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
```

It still doesn't work. Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem. This worked for me:

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/?id='+videoUrl+'&callback=?', function(data) {
                  if(data.shares == null) {
                      likeCount = 0;
                  } else {
                      likeCount = data.shares;
                  }
              }, 'json');
```

The "&callback=?" in the url causes jQuery to treat it as JSONP. See [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)
for a much more detailed explanation than I could provide here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because IE's support for CORS is quite bad and so wil only work in certain scenarios.
For best support you should use Facebook's FB.api via the JS SDK.