# Nothing happens with getJSON (JSONP)

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp

I have a valid JSON file on domain example1.com. It's just a PHP file with a header ('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'). The JSON on this page is valid.

I'm trying to parse the JSON on another domain. This is the script:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('www.example1.com?callback=?', function(data) {
        alert("lol")
    });
});
```

Why is the alert not working? It seems like the callback is never launched.

Comment: callbacks generally indicate it's `jsonp`, so you'd need to add `alert('lol')}, 'jsonp');`

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: Then look in your console at the network tab and see what's being returned. Pay close attention to the `status` which is likely `200`.

Comment: Are you sure it's valid JSONP and not just JSON (there is a difference).

Comment: This is the only thing the console gives me in the network tab: [21:02:53,582] GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 50ms]

Comment: how do I validate JSONP? I went on JSONlint.

Comment: Just see if it's wrapped in a function? According to the url, it should be JSONP.

Comment: What do you mean? It's just a json object.

Comment: Then it's not valid JSONP

Comment: I see. Do you have a link to something that show valid jsonp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp

Comment: not all API's provide `jsonp`, and some require special callback name. Check API docs

Comment: this is wat I did server side:
echo($_GET["jsoncallback"]."(".$json.")");

Comment: $json is json_encoded

Comment: That's great, it's still not JSONP, but if it's your server why do you need JSONP !

Comment: why is it still not jsonp valid? do I have to add the string function in front of the parentheses? And I need JSONP, because I'm trying to fetch the JSON object from another domain.

Comment: It's valid JSONP! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put http:// in the url.

http://www.example1.com?callback=?

Answer (score 0):

I think the json is bad from that url you're getting.

does it have echo "{}" ?

or echo json_encode($something) ?

it needs to return an empty json, or some json