# How to do a JSONP query in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsonp

How I can get my JSONP in IE7?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://host/index.php?param1=param1&callback=my_func">
</script>
```

Comment: It should work just as it does in other browsers? Create a function named `my_func` in the global scope, which handles the response. Are you seeing any particular errors in IE7?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work in IE, all other browthers work correct. IE7 does not have JSON support, and I don't know what i can do

Comment: You don't need JSON support to use JSONP; it's a bit of a misnomer; see [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2887209) or http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2011/10/json-vs-jsonp/. You really need to explain what *doesn't* work; do you see any errors? What have you tried to do to debug the issue? What sort of response does your call return? What's your response handling code?