# Different Result in Ajax Response when Request JSON from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, jsonp

I have working code

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laskarcyber/zr6jQ/)

```
var url = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/';        
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

That code yield 'success'. But when i change the json url (http://ip.jsontest.com/) to 'http://example.com' with this PHP code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$iii = array('ip' => '114.79.28.24' );
echo json_encode($iii);
?>
```

I got an error 
What's wrong?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp

Comment: You cannot use JSONP synchronously.

Comment: You do control http://example.com?

Answer (score 0):

dataType: "json" not "jsonp"

```
var url = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/';        
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        alert('success');
    } ,
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert(error);
    }
 });
```