# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" when parse jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have created a json webservice in ASP.NET.

```
URL http://mydomain:21130/JSONdata.aspx?Option=GetListRootMenus
```

Data return:

```
{"NumberOfMenu":"2", "Menus":[{"MenuKey":"menu_home", "MenuLevel":"1" },{"MenuKey":"menu_info", "MenuLevel":"1" }]}
```

After that, i parsed via JSONP

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p> this is a param </p>
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log("zc");
            $.ajax({
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: "http://mydomain:21130/JSONdata.aspx?Option=GetListRootMenus&callback=?",
                  success: function(data) {
                    console.log("123");
                  },
                  error: function(){
                    console.log("456");
                  }
            });
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but wrong. i don't know why :(
[image]

Comment: JSON and JSONP are two completely different things, despite the similar name. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2887209/218196 . Basically, if you tell jQuery to expect JSONP, you have to return JSONP, not JSON. We really should have a canonical answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in my comment, your service returns JSON, while jQuery expects JSONP. This is an issue because the response will be evaluated as JavaScript, but you are not sending back valid JavaScript.

Since you have control over the server, you have three possible solutions:

#### 1. Tell jQuery to expect JSON

If there are no cross-domain issues because the site itself is also served from that domain, simple let jQuery make a real Ajax request, by changing `dataType` to `json` and removing `callback=?` from the URL.

#### 2. Enable CORS (and tell jQuery to expect JSON)

If there are cross-domain issues, you can still do what I said in the first solution, but in addition, enable CORS on your server. In short, this allows other sites to make Ajax requests to your server. Have a look at http://enable-cors.org/ to learn how to enable it for your server.

#### 3. Return JSONP

JSONP is all about including JavaScript dynamically. This works across domains because `<script>` elements don't have the same-origin restriction that Ajax has. However, it is still something that the server has to support because it has to return valid JSON. If your JSON response was

```
{"foo": 42}
```

then the JSONP response would be

```
func({"foo": 42});
```

The name of the function (`func`) in this example, is taken from some GET parameter that you could choose arbitrarily, but most common is `callback`. jQuery will actually choose a random function name so it will send something like

```
callback=jQuery123135343456456
```

your service has to take that value and use it as function name for JSONP, i.e.

```
jQuery123135343456456({"foo": 42});
```

See also

- [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2067472/218196)
- [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2887209/218196)

Comment: Thanks so much. i 'll try and feedback the results

Comment: Just an extra tip: when Felix refers to the function what you need to do is add that function name to your call parameters: jsonpCallback: 'func'