# $.ajax not firing on IE, no errors

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I know IE8 has been around for a while, and there are many questions about similar problems. Solution not found in other questions thought I did add some nice ideas from other questions. Like don't use `$.getJSON` in IE and always use `cache: false` in IE8 calls.

So question is **why does this do not work in IE8**?
Did a `for ... in` loop but tried also to just *alert* inside the callback function and nothing. Feels like the ajax never gets fired...

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmx0yfy8/show

Only code in the page (besides loading jQuery in head):

```
$.ajax({
        url:"https://rawgit.com/umpirsky/country-list/master/country/cldr/en/country.json",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
         for (code in data){
        $('body').append('<div>' + code + '</div>'); 
    }; 
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Are you making a cross-domain ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the XHR console look like?

Try switching json to jsonp.

Reference: [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

```
$.ajax({
    type: GET,
    url:"https://rawgit.com/umpirsky/country-list/master/country/cldr/en/country.json",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
          $('body').append('<div>' + data.code + '</div>');
        });     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are doing a cross-domain AJAX call which IE 8 does not support. Your best choice is to do it through an `XDomainRequest`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx