# Angular HTTP Post Request, Payload is nested in JSON Object

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, http, cors

I am learning Angular and Node and I am trying to figure out how to have my Angular app hit a separate app hosting a rest API.

The request body is displayed as
`{ '{"name":"test"}': '' }`
and I expect it to be displayed as
`{ "name" : "test"}`

This is the front-end app that sends the post request.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/test',
  data: {
    "name": 'test'
  },
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

It is hitting the route defined as

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
 });
router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I expect the issue to be with the content-type being application/x-www-form-urlencoded but I cannot figure out how to allow cors with application/json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP can be used for performing CORS requests (more about json/jsonp here [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)), and in AngularJS documentation - [jsonp using $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That worked as well.

I read a little more about CORS and discovered the concept of pre-flighting and I added a function that would send a 200 reply to an application/json request and the above code works now.

Comment: Will do whenever the 4 minute timer is up. Thanks again :)