# jQuery UI autocomplete with different inputs

Tags: php, jquery-ui, input, autocomplete

I want to add different autocompletes for different inputs. For example I have the following two input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Max" required />
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Mustermann" required />
```

So I currently add different autocompletes as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#firstname' ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete_firstname.php',
        minLength: 1
    });
    $( '#lastname' ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete_lastname.php',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

That works fine for me, but maybe is there a better way like a parameter? So that I can use only one class on autocomplete fields and only one .php-file which return the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var focused_inp;

    $( '#firstname,#lastname' ).on('focus',function(){ focused_inp = $(this).prop('name');}).autocomplete({
        source: function(req, res){
      $.ajax({
      url: "autocomplete.php",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {action: focused_inp, data: request.term  },
      success: function(result) { res(result)  }
    }) },
        minLength: 1,

    });

});
```

Comment: that works, but can you tell me why **source: 'autocomplete.php?action='+$(this).prop('name'),** not working, but **source: 'autocomplete.php?action=firstname',** works?

Comment: is the result function required?

Comment: hm can't follow ... where come the data from for this result? my php-File echoing the following: **echo json_encode( $output );** and this looks like ["Maria","Martin",...]

Comment: ok, but I am getting an error now, for example I am typing a "m" then chrome say the requested url is now: 

autocomplete.php?action=firstname&term%5Bterm%5D=m

but it have to look like:
autocomplete.php?action=firstname&term=m

Comment: try to change data: req with data:decodeURIComponent(req)  or change request as post.

Comment: hm both not working, if I try to decode this uri the result looks weird:
**autocomplete.php?action=firstname&data=function+()%7Breturn+a.apply(b%7C%7Cthis%2Cc.concat(d.call(arguments)))%7D** and changing get to post and updating my php-File to handle post instead of get not working too

Comment: hm the request uri and the response looking great :), but I get no autocomplete dropdown now

Comment: thanks for your patience it is working now! :) ... but there is a "p" to much in your post, dataType: "json"

Comment: documentation about jsonp -->> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp

Comment: ahh ok sry, then ignore the last part of my last comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decouple your autocomplete instantiation code from the input markup, you can set your autocomplete source as a data attribute.

```
<input type="text" data-source="foo.php"/>
<input type="text" data-source="bar.php"/>
```

Then, in the [create](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) event, you can look for this attribute and set it as the source. This code is now applicable in many places, since you don't have to pass the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option directly when the widget is being created:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    create: function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            source = $this.data('source');
        if (source) {
            $this.autocomplete('option', 'source', source);
        }
    }
});

$('input').first().autocomplete('option', 'source');
// → 'foo.php'

$('input').last().autocomplete('option', 'source');
// → 'bar.php'
```