# Need Help parsing this JSON returned from a file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Sorry for basic question, but this doesn't seem like properly formed JSON to me.    I am reading this structure in from a file that returns this:

```
states([{"code":"AL","name":"Alabama"},{"code":"AK","name":"Alaska"},{"code":"AZ","name":"Arizona"}])
```

When I did a JSON Lint on this, it fails - but its what I have to work with, as this is a file on a server separate from mine.

I expected it to be var stores = [{stuff}],   I have yet to see the JSON saved like above, but again - I'm noob

I'm using Angular to read this in, so here's what I have in my code:

```
var directory = this;
directory.states = [];
$http.get('http://somesite.com/js/states.json').success(function(data){
    directory.states = data;
});
```

Here is the file I am having problems with:  http://massachusettswebdesigns.com/states.json

If I treat the states in the file as a variable, I get an undefined error:

```
var state = data.states;
```

Its not really a function either.

Any Ideas? I guess I could treat the whole thing as a string and split off the *states(* part, but I am thinking that there is an easier solution that I am just missing.

Comment: That is intended to be sourced into your page by a `<script>` tag - it's JSONP, not JSON.  Your page would have a global "states" function that would deal with the array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not correctly formatted `JSON`.  The formatting that you are showing is a function call (`states( . . . )`) that is taking a "`JSON`-like" array (`[ . . . ]`) of objects (`{"code":"XX","name":"yyyyy"}`) (per Pointy's comment, `JSONP`).

If it is being returned to you in a string format, you can use some string maniputation (`replace` or som kind of `RegExp` match) to trim out the function part of what is being returned and then parse the rest, and then you should be able to treat it like a `JSON` feed at that point.

**EDIT:** Pointy's comment is correct about it being `JSONP`.  If you are prepared to handle `JSONP`, then, that would be the proper way to work with it.  If not, then you can follow my suggestion of trimming out the "`JSONP` parts" and be able to use it, as if it were a `JSON` feed.

Here is a good SO thread on the differences between `JSON` and `JSONP`, for reference: [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

Comment: So this is JSONP,   I am still not 100% sure what to do now -  I can grab it in my data object - but then what do I need to do?

Answer (score -2):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)
The JSON looks valid to me taking out the outside status(). I agree it looks like a function call.

you would simply do:

```
var result = jinqJs().from('http://someurl').select();
```

OR

Async call

```
jinqJs().from('http://someurl', function(self) {result = self.select();});
```