# Ajax call using jsonp not working, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

## Problem

I'm working with a open data, city API for river levels, but when I make my ajax call using `jsonp` I receive an error for `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` which doesn't appear to be coming from my `scripts.js`

It is also my understanding that my ajax call might not be working because this API only spits out `XML` or `json`. I've tried to switch my `dataType: json`, but when I do that I receive the error below. Not particular sure if using jQuery's `.getJSON` is the best method to grab this data?

**Data:** http://opengov.brandon.ca/OpenDataService/opendata.html

**Documentation:** http://opengov.brandon.ca/api.aspx

### Error (when switching dataType: json)

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://opengov.brandon.ca/opendataservice/Default.aspx?date=riverlevel&columns=date&dataset=riverlevel. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

### scripts.js

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://opengov.brandon.ca/opendataservice/Default.aspx?date=riverlevel&columns=date&dataset=riverlevel',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the API support JSONP? It seems like the server is responsing to your JSONP `<script>` request by serving the data (apparently XML, with a leading `<`) instead of serving you a script. If the server doesn't serve you a script, you can't use JSONP, since JSONP works by loading a script response into a `<script>` element.

Comment: That url returns XML, so obviously you can't use JSONP.

Comment: The API returns XML, not JSON.

Comment: According to their documentation, "The default data format is XML, but can be changed by setting the format query variable to "json" to return JSON formatted data."

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in reading [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

A "JSONP response" from a server is actually an *executable script*. The client runs the executable script, and the script happens to contain the data you want, supplied as an argument to a function. If the server doesn't serve an executable script, that server does not support JSONP.

For your next error, see ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource). Ajax requests to other domains are not permitted, unless explicitly allowed by CORS headers (like the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/10636765#10636765)) from the server. Due to the same-origin policy, scripts on one origin are not allowed to access the contents of another origin. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a way for the server to relax the same-origin policy.

I would suggest contacting the providers of the API and requesting CORS support. In this case, it really is as simple as serving an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response. Per the [W3C's own security recommendations for CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#security):

> A resource that is publicly accessible, with no access control checks, can always safely return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header whose value is "`*`".

Alternatively, you can set up a reverse proxy server that fetches the API resources for you and serves them on your own origin, as noted in an answer on [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076439/710446). Since the same-origin policy is a browser restriction, you can have any server you control fetch the API resource and then serve the response to your browser.

Comment: How would I do the last thing you suggested to "set up a proxy server that fetches the API resources for you and serves them on your own origin."

Comment: @AndrewNguyen I added a little more about this, and linked to a simple `mod_proxy` Apache implementation, but the actual implementation will depend on what server-side technology you are using. At an abstract level, the browser needs to make a request to your *own server* (not to `opengov.brandon.ca`), and then that server performs a fetch of the `opengov.brandon.ca` resource, and finally it serves the contents of that fetch as the response to the browser's request.

Answer (score 2):

> The default data format is XML, but can be changed by setting the format query variable to "json" to return JSON formatted data.

You need to add `&format=json` to the end of the URL:

```
http://opengov.brandon.ca/opendataservice/Default.aspx?date=riverlevel&columns=date&dataset=riverlevel&format=json
```

Comment: So changing the URL in my AJAX call to add `&format=json`, does get rid of the first "Uncaught syntax error: unexpected token" but no object actually appears in the console.

Comment: Try removing `dataType: 'jsonp',`?

Comment: Removing **dataType: 'jsonp** gives this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://opengov.brandon.ca/opendataservice/Default.aspx?date=riverlevel&columns=date&dataset=riverlevel&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: It seems that the author of the API hasn't properly set up their service to allow other websites to request data. They would need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to allow CORS like @apsillers mentioned.