# GoogleMapsAPI's JSON "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: json, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I'm studying AngularJS.
I'm trying to get GoogleMapsAPI in JSON response format.
but Chrome reports "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ".

So far I am just trying to connect and see the objects information using the following code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Tokyo&destinations=Kyoto&mode=Driving&sensor=false', {
        params: {
            callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        console.dir(data,status,headers,config);
        deferred.resolve(data);   
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        deferred.reject(status);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
```

The JSON is coming back in the response, but Chrome reports "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "
I keep getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (18:20:02:095 | error, javascript)
  at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Tokyo&destinations=Kyoto&mode=Driving&sensor=false&callback=angular.callbacks._0:2
```

GoogleMapsApi's JSON Response:

```
    {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Kyoto, Kyoto Prefecture, Japan" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Tokyo, Japan" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "457 km",
                  "value" : 456931
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 hours 39 mins",
                  "value" : 20338
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

If I navigate directly to url itself, the JSON is returned and is displayed in the browser.

Any ideas why I can't get this error and I never make it to the success callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Google's Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) returns JSON, not JSONP.

[What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

Maybe try a normal [`$http.get()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) call; Angular will automatically parse the JSON response:

```
var promise = $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Tokyo&destinations=Kyoto&mode=Driving&sensor=false')
    .then(function(response){
        var data = response.data,
            status = response.status,
            headers = response.headers,
            config = response.config;
        console.dir(data,status,headers,config);
        return data; 
    }, function(response){
        var status = response.status;
        return status;
    });

return promise;
```

Comment: I didn't know the difference between JSON and JSONP. Thanks!  And I tried your advice , it was not possible. Please Can you check for this Link?https://jsfiddle.net/dt70sm/oa4h999w/1/

Comment: You're running into a [CORS](http://enable-cors.org) issue. To bypass this, you can use [a Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en) to disable the Same-Origin policy. This will lower your browser's security, so use the extension only as needed ;-)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Jsfiddle's sample is work by this extention. I gonna use this extention when need. Thankyou! :D