# AngularJS $http Unexpected token colon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I'm trying to do a get request to a remote website but I get: 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" 
Does any one have a idea what im doing wrong?
This is the code I have

```
var url = "http://www.colorfyit.com/api/swatches/list.json?url=facebook.com&callback=json_callback";

    $http.jsonp(url)
        .then(function successCallback(response) { 
            console.log(response); 
        }, function errorCallback(response) { 
            console.log(response); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the colorfyit api supports jsonp. The response from http://www.colorfyit.com/api/swatches/list.json?url=facebook.com&callback=json_callback is in JSON format, it's not wrapped in a function call as it would be if it was a JSONP response.

More info: [What are the differences between JSON and JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp)

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get json from another page with angular, or am I screwed on this one?

Comment: You can use $http.get(url) to get data (json) using angularjs, but you might run in to CORS issues...

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is that your url is malformed. You need ? before the first parameter and & before the following ones.

Comment: Thanks, have changed my question, and made it shorthand, my problem still exist tho