# How do I add in a specific value type for jsonp?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsonp

So my script right now is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").bind('click', function() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=' + username,
      data: {
        q: username
      },
      async: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp', //you may use jsonp for cross origin request
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Enter your idiom here">
<br>
<button id="submit" type="">Submit</button>
```

How do I make it so I can make this script work with the +username?
I need help on fixing this, this isn't my original code but I am just tinkering with it.  I am new to stuff like JS, JSON, etc.

Comment: Is expected result to set `username` at `input` element `change` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change event ?

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Roblox API doesn't implement JSONP.

Comment: when i tried another script, it wasn't with jsonp and it hard a CORS error.  I looked up on how I can fix it and it said use jsonp with cross domain.  Also go to the link 'http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=Shedletsky ' that's json right?  and also how is json different from jsonp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp?s=1|4.6480

Comment: JSONP only works if the API supports it. Since this API doesn't, you need to write a script on your own server that calls the API.

Comment: How do you call an API??

Comment: @Barmar also when i run the code it has an error stating "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement"

Comment: The way that JSONP works is that the it creates `<script src="http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=whatever&callback=func"></script>`. The server is supposed to return a script that contains `;func(jsonobject);`. If it just returns the JSON object, that's not a valid script, and you get an error.

Comment: @Barmar ohhh i understand. :/ i'll just give up on this project because i do not know what i am doing :|