# Simple XMLHttpRequest fails with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header null

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-post, cors

I am trying to get a simple random quote from API exposed in [here](http://forismatic.com/en/api/). It basically wants a POST request without any authorization. I want to achieve this using XMLHttpRequests. Here is the code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var forismaticUrl = 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/';
var params = 'method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en';

xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('POST', forismaticUrl, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

xhr.onload = function(response) {
    console.log('helloooo', response);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.responseText);
};

xhr.send(params);
```

Whatever I tried, my XMLHttpRequests always fail with error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

What am I doing wrong here? Can anybody help with the code and show me working XMLHttpRequest example with the forismatic API? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PatrickEvans I came up with that one as well. But I don't see any answer that says: `No, you cannot do it anyway using XMLHttpRequest`. Is the request possible with some configuration on the xhr object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Your browser is expecting the API service to support CORS, but it does not. You could try to [turn off CORS on your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) to help with debugging, but you should not go to production like that.

It's possible that service supports CORS's younger and weaker brother, [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp).

If not, and if this API service is unwilling to modernize, and if there are no alternatives available to you, you'll need to make your API calls server-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for acknowledging! My code will be on production, so what is your suggested workaround? I found out two solutions which are both ugly: **1) Jquery ajax call with jsonp**: I dont want to include jquery only for this. **2) Make a script tag and change its src attribute**: Way uglier than jquery :( I think it is not possible to use jsonp format with xmlhttprequest, right?  *btw there's no backend in my app, so there's no server-side*

Comment: **2** is basically what **1** does for jsonp anyway. If you have no *server side* and the API doesn't use CORS headers or JSONP, you're out of luck