# AJAX POST call with application/json contentType gets "no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" error

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, cors

I have the Javascript function below. Whenever I run it (calling it from an Android app using WebView), it is sent as an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` despite having the `dataType: "json"` attribute.

If I add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` then the request is not even received from the server and I get error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/api. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

The request headers look like this:

```
OPTIONS /api HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
```

The server is a Java Servlet running on Jetty Embedded that does not even have a WEB-INF or web.xml as it is not a web app but an API. The server does not even receive the request, so I guess it won't be solved by adding `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

**Response header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.0.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

**Client Javascript**

```
function create(userId, callback) {

  var submitData = {
    "action": "create",
    "userId": userId
  };

  $.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(submitData),
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.example.com/api",
    dataType: "json"
  })
  .done(function(data) { callback(SUCCESS); })
  .fail(function() { callback(UNKNOWN_ERROR); });
}
```

**EDIT:** Tried doing this request without JQuery and still doesn't work.

```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://www.example.com/api");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(submitData));
```

Comment: On what container is the servlet running? In tomcat you can easily configure a CORSFilter to allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: @Harald on Jetty

Comment: Maybe this document helps: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html

Comment: Try to add contentType : "application/json" to your ajax code.

Comment: @Harald it is jetty-embedded and I don't even have a web.xml in the entire application. It is loading all the dependencies from maven. Where can I add those conditions if I don't have a web.xml? It is not a web app.

Comment: @dsp_user as explained in the question, it triggers an error

Comment: Perhaps you can try with plain javascript (and set the header content type there  e.g.  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"). If it still doesn't work, you'll know it's not jQuery.

Comment: @dsp_user same error with plain javascript. I edited my question with a response header that is received.

Comment: If I'll have time, I'll try your code  when I get home tonight.

Comment: Also, some posts suggest using jsonp (json with padding) instead of json for CORS requests so you may try that as well(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp).

Comment: very interesting @dsp_user but jsonp seems to work only with GET requests and in my case it really has to be a POST

Comment: I see now that I had the same issue as you (but for a GET request) and I solved it by adding xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: @dsp_user I just tried that with POST and it doesn't work. I believe that header should be on the server side, right?

Comment: The header should be set on the client, that's what I did.

Comment: Still the same error, Arturo?

Comment: @dsp_user unfortunately still doesn't work (I copied your code and tried to run it against my jetty server). I believe I need to add some Access-Control code to my jetty config.

Comment: I hope you'll get it working soon. I've had issues with AJAX in the past that I wasn't able to resolve, so yes it can be tricky to make AJAX always work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I'm using `Tomcat`, not `Jetty` though). I didn't do anything with the `JSON` payload, just tested if the URL on the server is hit.

**AJAX (plain javascript)**

```
function issueAjaxPost(){
  var url = "http://localhost:8085/some_url/servlet/PostJson";
  var json = '{ "action": "create", "userId": userId }';

  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xmlhttp.send(json);
}
```

**Servlet**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException  {
  String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
  String page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"));

  ...

  if("/PostJson".equals(page)){
    response.setContentLength("success".length());
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().write("success");
  }
}
```

**AJAX callback (the result)**

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML = this.responseText;      //the result (success)
  }
};
```