# Can't get response from Java HttpServer with jquery Ajax

Tags: java, ajax

I have a Java Http Server running that responds with Hello World. The code is below.

```
public class ScannerHttpService {

    public static void startService() throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/jsp", new JspHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class JspHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "Hello World";
            //specify it before sendResponseHeaders()
            t.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=" + StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            System.out.println(t.getResponseHeaders().entrySet());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call this service using ajax and show the response in a alert window from a jsp page. I am using the following code.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Service Verification</title>
    <%--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getText(){
            var response = '';
            $.ajax({ type: "GET",
                url: "http://example.com:8000/jsp",

                success : function(text)
                {
                    response = text;
                },
                error : function()
                {
                    response = "Fail"
                }
            });

            alert(response);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form accept-charset="utf-8">
        <h3>Click Ready!</h3>
        <input type="submit" value="Ready" onclick="getText()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't get the response from the server. It is throwing the following error in browser.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com:8000/jsp. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). 1 (unknown)
```

Where am I doing wrong? I have access to both code. Both server and client are in the same network.

**EDIT:**
Following @Brian bcr666 Ray and @Sandeep's suggestion, I added

```
t.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

to the java code. It is working now.

Comment: See this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694651/ajax-post-call-with-application-json-contenttype-gets-no-access-control-allow/42701405#42701405 )

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Ajax call is originating from a UI which is hosted on some other domain than the server. You can enable CORS on your server for the `/jsp` endpoint and it should work.

Follow this: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

This `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy` means that you have your web page on one domain, but you are using javascript to ajax from another domain (example.com:8000). This is disallowed for security reasons.